# How can connect a Laravel Project to SQL instance on GCP?

Tags: laravel, google-cloud-platform, connection, hostname

For my project I'm currently using Laravel 5.8 and my database is deployed on gearhost.com. Their service provide an hostname (mysql2.gear.host), a database name and a user (same as the database name)

I use these data to make the connection in my .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=mysql2.gear.host
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=myDatabaseName
DB_USERNAME=myDatabaseName
DB_PASSWORD=myPassword
```

The service is a bit slow and I'm trying to move to GCP. I have already created an instance and a database. Now I'm trying to figure out how to get an hostname address, but I can't

Is there a way to get these same data of an instance created on GCP?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to connect to Cloud SQL from gearhost.com you can just follow the [Cloud SQL documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#php)

In order to set a username and a password you can set them with this command

```
gcloud sql users set-password root --host=% --instance [INSTANCE_NAME] --password [PASSWORD]
```

Then you can look for the connection name of your instance using this command:

```
gcloud sql instances describe [INSTANCE_NAME]
```

After this, you can connect to your Cloud SQL using the proxy following the procedure stated in the documentation. You will get a dbSocket address to connect

```
dbSocket = '/cloudsql/INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME';
mysqli = new mysqli(null, $dbUser, $dbPass, $dbName, null, $dbSocket);
```